# Jquery count div elements by class from list value

Tags: jquery, class, count, element

Hello i want to count all visible div Elements with the value form the list item.
Items witch are hidden have count 0
If i do the count by hand (item by item) it works, here my example:

```
 var counter = $(".green").length-$(".green.hidden").length;
```

Here is my page how i want to use it:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js">
</script>
<style>
  a {text-decoration: none; }
  div { border:1px solid grey; width:200px; height: 10px; margin:3px; }
  .black { background-color:black; }
  .blue { background-color:blue; }
  .green { background-color:green; }
  .hidden { visibility:hidden; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="list1"> 
  <li><a href="" value="">all<span></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="" value=".black">black<span></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="" value=".blue">blue<span></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="" value=".green">green<span></span></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="element black"></div>
<div class="element green hidden"></div>
<div class="element blue"></div>
<div class="element green "></div>
<script>
$(function(){
 var totalcount = 0;
 var counter = 0;
$("li a").each(function(){
 var counter = $(this).attr("value").length;
 var totalcount = totalcount+counter;

   $(this).find("span").html(" (" + counter + ") ");
});
   $("span", 'a[value|=""]').html(" (" + totalcount + ")");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The List have to look like this:
All (3)
black (1)
blue (1)
green (1)

Thanks in forward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `<a>` element has no attribute value, to count elements with classes that are visible do:

```
var all = $('.element').filter(":visible").length,
    green = $('.green:visible').length,

....etc
```

Note that elements that are just 'visibility:hidden" are considered visible, and this will not work on such elements.

Here's how I would do it:

HTML:

```
<ul id="list1"> 
  <li><a href="#" data-color="all">all<span></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-color="black">black<span></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-color="blue">blue<span></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-color="green">green<span></span></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="element black"></div>
<div class="element green hidden"></div>
<div class="element blue"></div>
<div class="element green "></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $.each($('li a'), function(index, item) {
        if ($(item).data('color')=='all') {
            $('span', item).text(' ('+$('.element:visible').length+')');
        }else{
            $('span', item).text(' ('+$('.'+$(item).data('color')+':visible').length+')');
        }
    });
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/aTcR5/)

Comment: Hello adeno, thanks thats close to that what i need. I want to include a counter i a other script. So the values of the list are given. The value All have to be empty '' and the other values need to have the point (.black) in the begin.  Can you help me again?

Comment: If for some reason you can't change everything, heres something a litter closer [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/aTcR5/1/), but you should use the data atttribute as `<a>` elements does not have a value, and using just a regular value will from my experience give just give you grief.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but for that first example you could do

```
var counter = $('div.element').not('.hidden').length
```

Answer (score -1):

You're not far off with your JavaScript.

```
var counter = $($(this).attr("value")).length;
```

What you currently have is the length of the value of the attribute that you've retrieved (hope that made sense!), but what you need to do is then use jQuery to get all elements with that class and see how many there are.

Here's an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fu8Ye/3/). I actually think your totalcount is calculated wrong, it shouldn't add the counter values because you'll end up with 4, what you would want to do is something more like:

```
var totalcount = $('.element').length;
```

And this can be done outside of the each loop.

Comment: The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property; however, the .length property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call. And again, a `<a>` element has no value, use either data atributes or something else.

Comment: good point, changed from `.size()` to `.length` and updated the example